# Hide all images on a page in Firefox (plain text only)

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Can I hide all images displayed on a page in Firefox?
I want to view the page in plain text only (with no images).

Is there any Firefox add-on for this?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need an extension in order to do this.  Simply go into your options, and under the content tab, unselect `Load Images Automatically`.  Note that most of the formatting will be preserved.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a bookmarklet, which work on almost, if not all, web browsers.

Here is a link with a good list of them, Zap images is probably the one you are looking for: https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/zap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Image-Show-Hide](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/232/)** add-on.

> Simply turn on | off images on all web-pages and (optional) auto-reload
>   current

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Accessibility Evaluation Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/5809/) and disable images and almost whatever objects you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Quickimage**](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/quickimage/?src=search) to hide pictures in one click, before webpage loading:

> Allow, block or prevent third-party images from loading via button in
>   the Status Toolbar or alternatively add a button to the Navigation
>   Toolbar. Hide pictures in one clic, before webpage loading.

Answer (score 0):

Search in protocol about, typing **about:config** in ff address bar. Then search for property **permissions.default.image** and set its value to **2**. Next time You load webpage it will be purged from images.

it is possible also to prevent from auto playing media, by following setup:

```
media.autoplay.allow-extension-background-pages false
media.autoplay.block-event.enabled  true
media.autoplay.block-webaudio   true
media.autoplay.default  5   or 2
media.autoplay.ask-permission true
media.autoplay.enabled.user-gestures-needed true # this enable setup in preferences
media.autoplay.allow-muted false</br>
media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.enabled  false
```