# Disable CSS In Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am currently running on a slow connection (20 KBPS) as I have used my internet quaota I was running on 90MBPS.

Anyway is there a way to disable CSS in all pages like you can disable JS in chrome, or any other methods to make browsing faster?

Comment: what's a screen reader? first time ive heard of it lol
Thanks for your help so far

Comment: A screen reader typically is used for those with bad vision - it reads the text out. However, there are programs, like Lynx, which renders only the text (in the same way a screen reader will only read text). I think your issue is not the CSS, but the size of the page - remember, just because an image isn't visible doesn't mean they didn't get loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the Chrome Web Developer Plugin. In the CSS section you can disable all CSS (or selectively just parts of it like ie inlines)

CSS usually are not that heavy on the other side but will make pages quite messy sometimes. Maybe disabling images / flash data may save you more bandwidth.

Comment: it seems to go alot faster when not loading images and disable css might make some pages unusable so it might be best to leave that

(i'm know some web developing)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try a text only browser if you really want to bring down as little as possible but this means with out pictures too -

http://lynx.browser.org/‎

> Lynx is a text browser for the World Wide Web.

Also see this question [how to view only text from a website](https://superuser.com/questions/402012/how-to-view-only-text-from-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Pendule plugin](http://www.chromeextensions.org/webmaster-seo/pendule/#.U7wnE_ndWE4) by downloading from that location and then going to the extensions page (chrome://extensions) and dragging pendule-0.0.3.crx onto the page, and click the "Add" button when prompted.